phpMyAdmin で Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Table/ColumnsDefinition.php#424 というエラーを解決したい
phpMyAdminで「構造」の項目をクリックして、カラムの内容を「変更」をクリックしたらエラーが起こります。エラーは無視しておりますが、それでも起こると面倒です。
私はMAMPで開発を行なっており、VSCodeでPHPのコードを書き、実際にphpMyAdminとMAMPの接続は成功しております。
ポート番号は80です。
http//:8889localhost/phpMyAdmin5/index.php
だと接続されません。

発生しているエラー
Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Table/ColumnsDefinition.php#424
 Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead

Backtrace

ClassLoader.php#571: include(./libraries/classes/ErrorHandler.php)
ClassLoader.php#428: Composer\Autoload\includeFile(string '/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin5/vendor/composer/../../libraries/classes/Table/ColumnsDefinition.php')
ChangeController.php#112: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass(string 'PhpMyAdmin\\Table\\ColumnsDefinition')
ChangeController.php#50: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\Structure\ChangeController->displayHtmlForColumnChange(array)
Routing.php#192: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\Structure\ChangeController->__invoke(
,
array,
)
index.php#44: PhpMyAdmin\Routing::callControllerForRoute(
,
string '/table/structure/change',
,
,
)

補足情報
データベースサーバ
サーバ： Localhost via UNIX socket
サーバの種類： MySQL
サーバの接続： SSLは使用されていません ドキュメント
サーバのバージョン： 5.7.39 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
プロトコル バージョン: 10
ユーザ： root@localhost
サーバの文字セット: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MAMPのバージョンはMAMP PRO 6です。
Webサーバ
Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2u PHP/8.2.0 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.18 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.30.1
データベースクライアントのバージョン： libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.0
PHP 拡張: mysqli ドキュメント curl ドキュメント mbstring ドキュメント
PHP のバージョン: 8.2.0
phpMyAdminのバージョン情報： 5.2.0
